unable to add color to zstyle completion
I am using eza instead of ls and have made changes in .zshrc
alias ls="eza --icons=always"

I want to add colors to my zstyle completion
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"

but this command is not working because I don't have LS_COLORS, how can I use eza colors in zstyle completion.
I tried this command
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors \
  'default:bg=blue' \
  'file:bg=blue' \
  'directory:bg=cyan' \
  'link:bg=magenta' \
  'executable:bg=green'

but this is also not working

The format for list-colors is similar to GNU's LS_COLORS, without the colons. Example:
COMP_COLORS='rs=0 di=38;5;27 ln=38;5;51 mh=44;38;5;15 pi=40;38;5;11 so=38;5;13 do=38;5;5 bd=48;5;232;38;5;11 cd=48;5;232;38;5;3 or=48;5;232;38;5;9 mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15 su=48;5;196;38;5;15 sg=48;5;11;38;5;16 ca=48;5;196;38;5;226 tw=48;5;10;38;5;16 ow=48;5;10;38;5;21 st=48;5;21;38;5;15 ex=38;5;34 *.tar=38;5;9 *.tgz=38;5;9 *.arc=38;5;9 *.arj=38;5;9 *.taz=38;5;9 *.lha=38;5;9 *.lz4=38;5;9 *.lzh=38;5;9 *.lzma=38;5;9 *.tlz=38;5;9 *.txz=38;5;9 *.tzo=38;5;9 *.t7z=38;5;9 *.zip=38;5;9 *.z=38;5;9 *.Z=38;5;9 *.dz=38;5;9 *.gz=38;5;9 *.lrz=38;5;9 *.lz=38;5;9 *.lzo=38;5;9 *.xz=38;5;9 *.bz2=38;5;9 *.bz=38;5;9 *.tbz=38;5;9 *.tbz2=38;5;9 *.tz=38;5;9 *.deb=38;5;9 *.rpm=38;5;9 *.jar=38;5;9 *.war=38;5;9 *.ear=38;5;9 *.sar=38;5;9 *.rar=38;5;9 *.alz=38;5;9 *.ace=38;5;9 *.zoo=38;5;9 *.cpio=38;5;9 *.7z=38;5;9 *.rz=38;5;9 *.cab=38;5;9 *.jpg=38;5;13 *.jpeg=38;5;13 *.gif=38;5;13 *.bmp=38;5;13 *.pbm=38;5;13 *.pgm=38;5;13 *.ppm=38;5;13 *.tga=38;5;13 *.xbm=38;5;13 *.xpm=38;5;13 *.tif=38;5;13 *.tiff=38;5;13 *.png=38;5;13 *.svg=38;5;13 *.svgz=38;5;13 *.mng=38;5;13 *.pcx=38;5;13 *.mov=38;5;13 *.mpg=38;5;13 *.mpeg=38;5;13 *.m2v=38;5;13 *.mkv=38;5;13 *.webm=38;5;13 *.ogm=38;5;13 *.mp4=38;5;13 *.m4v=38;5;13 *.mp4v=38;5;13 *.vob=38;5;13 *.qt=38;5;13 *.nuv=38;5;13 *.wmv=38;5;13 *.asf=38;5;13 *.rm=38;5;13 *.rmvb=38;5;13 *.flc=38;5;13 *.avi=38;5;13 *.fli=38;5;13 *.flv=38;5;13 *.gl=38;5;13 *.dl=38;5;13 *.xcf=38;5;13 *.xwd=38;5;13 *.yuv=38;5;13 *.cgm=38;5;13 *.emf=38;5;13 *.axv=38;5;13 *.anx=38;5;13 *.ogv=38;5;13 *.ogx=38;5;13 *.aac=38;5;45 *.au=38;5;45 *.flac=38;5;45 *.mid=38;5;45 *.midi=38;5;45 *.mka=38;5;45 *.mp3=38;5;45 *.mpc=38;5;45 *.ogg=38;5;45 *.ra=38;5;45 *.wav=38;5;45 *.axa=38;5;45 *.oga=38;5;45 *.spx=38;5;45 *.xspf=38;5;45'

zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "$COMP_COLORS"

